# (Discord.js) How to detect when user is starting/stopping to speak in specific voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I know there are following option in the documentation like [.speaking](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceState)

I'm trying to find a handler, like
`client.on('start/stop speaking', ...)` but I didn't find anything about something like this. Can someone help me with this please? I don't like to set an interval with a 0 delay and check all members in channel every time. I know how to get user and channel, but I can't figure out how make a handler for speaking

Comment: Hi user, welcome to SO. Could you please update your question and share the relevant code that you are currently stuck with ? Tyhank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`guildMemberSpeaking`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberSpeaking)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an event called `voiceStateUpdate` according to the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate). There is also a **read only** key called `.speaking`. The `oldState` and `newState` are members of the [VoiceState](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) class.

And this is how it works:

```js
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {
     // Do anything here with the updated state.
     if(oldState.speaking !== newState.speaking) {

        // User started speaking
     }
});
```